# Whitespaces in the path of the file:///

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that should print the file location in CLI and open it directly from the cli by clicking on it.
I've checked the same topics on StackOverflow and didn't find the solution yet.
Sove of the solutions suggested to represent a string as a raw string. It didn't work for me. The example of the link is below.
To represent the filepath as a link in CLI I used the `file:///` at the beginning of the file link

```
urllib.parse.urljoin('file:', "home/Desktop/test/organized/Status history.txt")
```

If I will click on the link in the link from the CLI it will be obviously truncated with the error message:

> Cannot find file
> home/Desktop/test/organized/**Status**

I used the following suggestions:

1. Represent the path as a raw string
2. Skip the spaces with backslashes

Could you please advise how to print the link to the file?

Comment: The ability to open a file by clicking a link printed to the terminal is very terminal-dependent and you should probably read the documentations for whichever terminal you are targeting. However, since you are using a `file://` uri, your best bet is probably URL-encode it (e.g. change the space to `%20`)

Comment: It's a URL, you have to [url quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) the string.

Comment: In case if I will use the url quote the local path will be : "home/Desktop/test/organized/Status%20history.txt". And ones I will try to open it I will get the error: Cannot find file home/Desktop/test/organized/Status%20history.txt
P.S I am using PyCharm CLI to print the path

Comment: @shapale Is the code in a folder 1 directory above ```home``` itself? If not, then you have a relative vs absolute URL problem. That ```Status%20history.txt``` should work IF the ```home``` directory itself is in the same directory as the code calling the URL. If not, you may have to provide something like ```./home/Desktop/home``` or ```../home/Desktop``` or ```C://full/path/to/home```. If the code itself is in the home directory, then your URL should look like this: ```Desktop/test/organized/Status%20history.txt ```

Comment: @Shapale, If you saw the above reply of mine, see the edit. Also, I would be able to provide a better answer if I knew the directory Tree of the code and that actual file location. Everything else is a guess.

Comment: @BrandonStivers thanks for your reply. Yes.  the home directory itself is in the same directory. THe problem is that when the url is printed in the CLI of PyCharm the whitespace breaks the link and the link to the file is giving the error:
`Cannot find file home/Desktop/test/organized/Status` which is reasonable because the white space breaks the link:
`"home/Desktop/test/organized/Status history.txt"`

Comment: Adding %20 where the space is should not break the link. While I am thinking about it, I don't think ```file:///home/Desktop``` is a valid absolute URI on a window machine. You have to include ```file:///c:/USERS/username/Desktop``` or ```file:///%userprofile%/Desktop``` but it's been a long time since I targeted anything Windows. LOL

Comment: @BrandonStivers . Thank you for suggestion but I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: If you aren't on Windows, then change ```c://USERS/Desktop``` to ```$HOME/Desktop``` or ```~/Desktop``` or ```/home/your_username/Desktop```.

That said, why is your code sitting in the root directory? Shouldn't you be working out of your home directory at the very least?